# Winter Bash 2013 leader board missing the tooltip for hats

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash-2013

The leader board for winter bash 2013 does not have a tool tip when hovering the mouse over the hats (in a specific site board, for example: [superuser](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/superuser.com)). For curious people like me this is an annoying issue. In addition to that, these hats' icons are not clickable, making the only option to kill that curiosity is by visiting the main winter bash site and making a visual matching, just annoying :/

Can this be added?

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the image, my MS Paint skills are not that good...

Comment: Hey, it's still a free-hand circle, so +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fair point; those hats have tooltips now.